# stack activity in android

Tags: java, android

Hi i am working with android , and i have a problem with the activity stack. As i know, when someone uses the back button, reload the back activity. But in the case i have many layouts shown from one activity, how can i go back to them.

Here is the deal, i am using a listview filled with categories, and when i press an item, i reuse the activity and the layout, to show its subcategories. So what i need is to came back no to the back activity, not to the back layout, but to the back "state".

Well, the idea is simple, first i show all the categories with no parent, then when i pressed an item, i show its subcategories.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is creating two `Activities` - for categories and for subcategories. If you try to implement all the logic in a single `Activity` you won't earn nothing and just end up totally confused. Using `Activities` simplifies things a lot just because it handles problems such as yours. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. The problem is that those subcategories also has its own subcategories. And those, has other subcategories, etc.. And the problem is that i dont knwo how far it would go

Comment: @user1568613, There is no need to implement a tonn of similar Activities, just implement one Activity for subcategories and fill it with data dynamically.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, thats exactly what i am doing, but when i press the back button i want  the application to show the back state. no to reload the all activity. Also i am using a tabhost. with one tab for code search and the other for category search. Any idea

Answer (score 1):

Check out Fragments, they are the stepping stone between a view and an activity. An activity can have multiple fragments and will manage their back stack (if you tell it to).
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

You'll have to use the support library to used them on pre honeycomb devices.

Comment: thank you very much, but daes it work also with android 2.0 ? .. As far as i read, it doesnt =9

Comment: The support library back ports Fragments to API lvl 4, so... 1.6 off the top of my head - defiantly before v2 http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: Also, if you're going to have _alot_ of sub categories, you can relaunch the same activity with parameters in its intent that'll load the sub category and it'll keep the back stack. Memory reasons this might be optimal

Comment: yeeap... i am doing that, but i need to return to the subcotagories i saw before, the all activity would reload